# heap corruption detected after normal block at delete row

Tags: c++, arrays

hello i call the function "add" 3 times and in the third call its give me this error: "heap corruption detected after normal block"

header file:

```
template <class T>  
class Array
{

private:    
   T* myArray;
   int size;
public:     
   Array(); 
   Array(int _size);        
   void add(T object);  
   void remove(T Object);   
   int getSize();   
   ~Array();
};
```

function "add" in class Array:

```
    template <class T>
void Array<T>::add(T object)
{

    T* tempArr = new T(size + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = myArray[i];
    }
    tempArr[size] = object;
    size++;

    if (myArray != NULL)
        delete[] myArray;    <------- "in this line its give me the error in the third time"
    myArray = tempArr;
}
```

Comment: `new[]`/`delete[]` `new/delete`

Comment: Use the `new[]` form for the new to match the `delete[]`. Or the `new` matched with `delete`.

Comment: This is a slow reimplementation of `std::vector`... You should pre-allocate more elements than currently needed. Store the allocated size in another member. Only re-allocate if this number is going to be exceeded, and if size drops below some threshold. Also you need to implement copy constructor and copy assignment operator, or disable both ("rule of three").

Comment: Watch the fireworks come out when you try to assign or copy your `Array` instances.  This means that you should post the main() program you're testing, as your heap corruption may still exist due to not taking care of the copying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As it is perfectly said in the comments, you should use that delete operator which corresponds to your usage of new

in the add function:

```
template <class T>
void Array<T>::add(T object)
{

    T* tempArr = new T[size + 1];  // with this, you use new[] ...

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = myArray[i];
    }
    tempArr[size] = object;
    size++;

    if (myArray != NULL)
        delete[] myArray;          // so you should use delete[] here.
    myArray = tempArr;
}
```

2) Check if myArray is initialized to NULL in the constructor, because there isn't a default value assigned to pointers in C++.

in the constructor:

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(void)
{
   myArray = NULL;  // must do it, otherwise it will get some memory junk as value
}
```

Regards

Comment: I do not exactly understand can you give some example maby..?

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
T* tempArr = new T(size + 1);
```

doesn't allocate an array. It allocates **a single** `T` and initializes it with the **value** `size + 1`.

What you want is (note the `[]`s):

```
T* tempArr = new T[size + 1];
```